# Can not change Switch text on/off at runtime

Tags: android

I have an issue where I can't change [Switch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) textOn/textOff content at runtime. This means, that the following code, bound to a simple Button (for testing purposes) does not work:

```
private int _counter = 1;
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
  _sw.setTextOn("On " + _counter);
  _sw.setTextOff("Off " + _counter);
  _sw.setText("Text" + _counter);
  _sw.setVisibility(_sw.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
  _counter  ++;
  _sw.invalidate(); // no effect
  _sw.setFocusable(true); // no effect
  _sw.getTextOn(); // returns the correct value which was set above
}
```

This code changes the text (`setText` method works) associated with Switch, but not On or Off labels on the switch. Interestingly enough, if I call `getTextOn` or `getTextOff`, I get back the correct value(s), that were set on this Switch. Any ideas why this does not work as expected?

Regards,

Miha.

Comment: does it work if you do android:textOn="blabla" in xml?

Comment: @Warlock, yes, it surely works. But I want to change it during runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a lack of better approach (I'm open to suggestions), I used an ugly reflection hack to fix this. I have a class which extends Switch, where I implemented the following method:

```
@Override
public void requestLayout() {
    IslLog.i(TAG, "requestLayout");
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field mOnLayout = Switch.class.getDeclaredField("mOnLayout");
        mOnLayout.setAccessible(true);
        mOnLayout.set(this, null);
        java.lang.reflect.Field mOffLayout = Switch.class.getDeclaredField("mOffLayout");
        mOffLayout.setAccessible(true);
        mOffLayout.set(this, null);
    } catch (Exception x) {
        Log.e(TAG, x.getMessage(), x);
    }
    super.requestLayout();
}
```

This now works. After I use `setTextOn` or `setTextOff`, I just call `requestLayout`, which uses reflection to set `mOnLayout` and `mOffLayout` to null; `requestLayout` in turn triggers `onMeasure`, which re-initializes those variables. It is ugly, but it works and is, IMHO better than copying the complete source of Switch to application.

Comment: Good stuff.  Anyone know how/what/why the Switch doesn't work as is?  Wondering if this is a bug or...?  Thanks again.

Comment: @K.R.: sorry, I have no idea.